# Unable to filter CSV columns stored in dataframe in spark 2.2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a CSV file from my local machine using spark and scala and storing into a dataframe (called `df`). I have to select only few selected columns with new aliasing names from the `df` and save to new dataframe `newDf`. I have tried to do the same but I am getting the error below.

```
main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`history_temp.time`' given input columns: [history_temp.time, history_temp.poc]
```

Below is the code written to read the csv file from my local machine.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DataLoadConversion {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/spark-warehouse")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("DataConversion").getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
      .option("inferSchema","true")
      .load("file:///C:/Users/an/Desktop/ct_temp.csv")

    df.show(5)   // Till this code is working fine

    val newDf = df.select("history_temp.time","history_temp.poc")
```

Below are the code which I tried but not working.

```
//  val newDf = df.select($"history_temp.time",$"history_temp.poc")
//  val newDf = df.select("history_temp.time","history_temp.poc")
//  val newDf = df.select( df("history_temp.time").as("TIME"))
//  val newDf = df.select(df.col("history_temp.time"))

//  df.select(df.col("*"))    // This is working

    newDf.show(10)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data (including the header you are using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the looks of it. your column name format is the issue here.  i am guessing they are  just regular stringType but when you have something like history_temp.time spark thinks it as an arrayed column.  which is not the case.  I would rename all of the columns and replace "." to "*". then you can run the same select and it should work.  you can use foldleft to rplace all "." with "*" like below.

```
val replacedDF = df.columns.foldleft(df){ (newdf, colname)=>
newdf.withColumnRenamed (colname, colname.replace(".","_"))
}
```

With that done you can select from  replacedDF with below

```
val newDf= replacedDf.select("history_temp_time","history_temp_poc")
```

Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: I have tried the below and it worked.  `val newDf = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((curr, n) => curr.withColumnRenamed(n, n.replace(".", "_")))  
val finalDf = newDf.select(newDf("history_temp_time").as("TIME")`

Comment: Thank you. Work with the solution provided by you.

Comment: sure Np.  glad to have helped.